# Abstract Classes in PHP throwing error

Tags: php, oop, methods, abstract-class

I have be below test script, and I am not sure as to why is is giving me errors. But at the same time working as expected (outputting a text 'woof');

```
abstract class Animal { 

abstract function bark(); 
  function MakeDog(){
        return $this->bark();
  } 

} 

class Dog extends Animal { 
  function bark(){
    echo 'Woof';
  }
} 


$dog = new Dog(); 
echo $dog->MakeDog()->bark(); // this outputs 'woof' but with error. 


Fatal error: Call to a member function bark() on a non-object in [...] 26
```

Line 26 is `//echo $dog->MakeDog()->bark();`
I am not sure to what the error is related to.

Comment: Hint: Have a look at the `bark` function's return value.

Comment: `return` does not even echo out the text, so I doubt it is from the return value/

Comment: That's not what I meant. In `MakeDog`, you return the return value of `bark`, however `bark()` does not contain a return statement and thus implicitly returns `NULL`. Then you try to call `bark()` again on `NULL` (because that's what is returned by `makeDog`), which results in the given error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't call `bark()` after the method `MakeDog()` and you can't use echo for return a message, for this use "return", the correct code:

```
<?php

abstract class Animal { 

    abstract function bark(); 

    public function MakeDog(){
        return $this->bark();
    } 

} 

class Dog extends Animal { 

    function bark(){
        return 'Woof';
    }

} 

$dog = new Dog(); 

echo $dog->MakeDog();

?>
```

Comment: What if I wanted to call it like this `echo $dog->MakeDog()->bark();`?

Comment: Hi, the only way to do that was if the method "MakeDog" return the instance of the class, I encourage you to read about "Singleton", is something quite simple.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I am sure there is a way to achieve that without tapping on singletons. I'm just having trouble figuring this out.

Comment: You can return $this on MakeDog method and call this way echo $dog->MakeDog()->bark();

Comment: Perfect, just what I was looking of

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you don't need to echo even. This should work

```
$dog = new Dog();
$dog->MakeDog()->bark();
```

Also, get rid of `return` just invoke `bark()` in the `MakeDog` function

```
function MakeDog() {
    $this->bark();    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Shouldn't it just be:

```
$dog = new Dog();
echo $dog->MakeDog();
```

Your function MakeDog already executes the method bark().

Comment: Nope, I need bark to be appended to the `MakeDog()` method